# 32 bit protected mode boot loader cursor racing across screen without display code?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm writing a basic kernel from scratch using https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf as my textbook. I have written the basic 16 bit boot loader, and I just wrote the code to switch to protected mode based on this article. it defines a basic general descriptor table, loads it, and flips a bit in the cr0 special register. However, when I try to boot the code, I get a cursor racing across the bottom of the screen repeatedly. This I can't understand because I haven't displayed anything yet. When I tried to display a string, I got only the cursor at the bottom of the screen still. Here is some of my code.

```
BITS 16
; switch to 32 bit protected mode
switch_to_pm:

    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

BITS 32

init_pm:

    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    ;mov ebp, 0x90000
    ;mov esp, ebp

BEGIN_PM:
    ;mov ebx, 0xb8000
    ;mov ah, 0x0f
    ;mov al, '3'
    ;mov [ebx], ax
    ;add ebx, 2
    ;mov al, '2'
    ;mov [ebx], ax
    jmp $
```

this is the part that does the switch. It is called from the main boot_loader file. If that code is needed I can edit my question to include it. Thank you guys. I really can't figure out the problem, but this is my first time writing a 32 bit boot loader.

boot_loader.asm:

```
BITS 16
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    mov bp, 0x9000 ; setup our stack
    mov sp, bp

    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load
    call switch_to_pm

    jmp $


disk_load:
    push dx
    mov bx, 0x1000 ; adress to write to
    mov dh, 15     ; # sectors to read
    mov ah, 0x02   ; sector to start at ??
    mov al, dh     ; same # sectors
    mov ch, 0x00   ; cylinder to read ?
    mov dh, 0x00   ; head to read (switch?)
    mov cl, 0x02   ; sector to start at ??

    int 0x13

    jc disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp dh, al
    jne disk_error
    ret

disk_error:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bx, DISKERR
    sub bx, 1
disk_error_print:
    add bx, 1
    cmp byte [bx], 0x0
    je disk_error_done
    mov al, [bx]
    int 0x10
    jmp disk_error_print
disk_error_done:
    jmp $


%include "boot/gdt.asm"
%include "boot/switch_to_pm.asm"


; Global vars
BOOT_DRIVE: db 0
DISKERR:
    db "error reading disk" , 0
; Bootsector padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
db "hello"
```

gdt.asm:

```
gdt_start:

gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
gdt_code: ; the code segment descriptor
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    dw 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_data: ; the data segment descriptor
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    dw 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Comment: Can you just show us all your code please? A Minimal Complete Verifiable example is your best bet to get an answer.

Comment: I listed the complete code @MichaelPetch thanks. also, I would really appreciate if the person who voted to close my question could help me understand what about my question is a problem and how I can make it better. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to build your bootloader and ran it in both QEMU and BOCHS, and your bootloader runs and prints `error reading disk` . The parameters for your disk read look wrong. You suggest you have a cursor moving across the screen? I don't see that. What commands do you use to build the bootloader and then what commands to run it? Which Emulator do you use? And is the code you posted what you are actually using?

Comment: If you comment out the call to `disk_load` because of the bugs and just deal with the problem with the _GDT_ then you should be able to get somewhere.First off near the start of your bootloader you should explicitly set _DS_ to zero because you use an ORG of 0x7c00. Add `xor ax,ax` `mov ds, ax` . The main issue is that you have bugs in the GDT  `gdt_code` and `gdt_data`. Both start with  `dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    dw 0x0` The problem is that the last 0x00 should be a byte and not a word. Change both to be `dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0` . This causes ill-formed GDT entries.

Comment: Once you resolve that you should be able to uncomment the code that prints 32 in the upper left of the display and in theory it should work

Comment: Since this is more or less debugging and there are other answers similar but not exact, and likely this question won't be useful to others I'll offer these fixed up files (including disk access bug fixes and the GDT fixes) with a few comments: http://capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/39713303

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not using an emulator but rather writing the assembled code to the first sector of a disk image file created by `dd if=/dev/zero of=os-image.img bs=512 count=100` and writing this image to a flash drive and then rebooting. that might be why the disk_load function doesnt work for you, did you use a big enough image file? it worked for me. but as i said this is all new and i just took the GDT out of that pdf i linked. thank you again.